# send msg from senders to receivers (in concurrency mode) in java

Tags: multithreading, sockets, networking

I want to write program that use one server that receive msg from reporters in specific port and send online msg to client (readers) that are connected on another specific port ...

tip1 => 
my server has two open port ... one specific for senders and another for reader...

tip2 =>
when msg is received from sender in server => we(server) should send this msg to all online client that listen

how can I implement them...
I have problem in send msg from server to "all" client!

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this -

```
public class SenderReceiver {

    private static volatile boolean serverStarted;
    private static final String SERVER_HOST = "127.0.0.1";
    private static final int SERVER_PORT = 25000;
    private static final List<ReceiverConnectionHandler> handlers = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<ReceiverConnectionHandler>();
    private static final ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // start server
        executorService.submit(new SenderReceiver().new Server());
        // wait until started
        while (!serverStarted) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(100);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        // start receiver threads
        int i = 0;
        while (i++ < 10) {
            executorService.submit(new Receiver(SERVER_HOST, SERVER_PORT));
        }
        // start sender threads
        i = 0;
        while (i++ < 5) {
            executorService.submit(new Sender(SERVER_HOST, SERVER_PORT));
        }
    }

    private class Server implements Runnable {
        public void run() {
            try {
                ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(SERVER_PORT);
                serverStarted = true;
                System.out.println("Server started");
                while (true) {
                    Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();
                    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
                    String connectionName = br.readLine();
                    if ("sender".equals(connectionName)) {
                        executorService.submit(new SenderConnectionHandler(br, handlers));
                    } else {
                        ReceiverConnectionHandler handler = new ReceiverConnectionHandler(socket);
                        handlers.add(handler);
                        executorService.submit(handler);
                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    private class SenderConnectionHandler implements Runnable {
        private BufferedReader br;
        private List<ReceiverConnectionHandler> handlers;

        public SenderConnectionHandler(BufferedReader br, List<ReceiverConnectionHandler> handlers) {
            this.br = br;
            this.handlers = handlers;
        }

        public void run() {
            try {
                String message;
                while ((message = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    Thread.sleep(1000); // just allowing all clients to be registered
                    for (ReceiverConnectionHandler handler : handlers) {
                        handler.update(message);
                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                if (br != null) {
                    try {
                        br.close();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }

        }
    }

    private class ReceiverConnectionHandler implements Runnable {
        private Socket receiverSocket;
        private final BlockingQueue<String> messages = new LinkedBlockingQueue<>();

        public ReceiverConnectionHandler(Socket socket) {
            this.receiverSocket = socket;
        }

        public void run() {
            BufferedWriter bw = null;
            try {
                bw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(receiverSocket.getOutputStream()));
                String message;
                while ((message = messages.poll(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)) != null) {
                    bw.write(message);
                    bw.newLine();
                    bw.flush();
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                if (bw != null) {
                    try {
                        bw.close();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }

        }

        public void update(Object message) {
            if (message instanceof String) {
                messages.add((String) message);
            }
        }
    }
}

class Sender implements Runnable {
    private static AtomicInteger senderCount = new AtomicInteger(0);
    private String serverHost;
    private int serverPort;

    public Sender(String serverHost, int serverPort) {
        this.serverHost = serverHost;
        this.serverPort = serverPort;
    }

    public void run() {
        BufferedWriter bw = null;
        try {
            Socket socket = new Socket(serverHost, serverPort);
            int senderNumber = senderCount.incrementAndGet();
            bw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream()));
            bw.write("sender");
            bw.newLine();
            String message = "This is a test message from sender " + senderNumber;
            bw.write(message);
            bw.newLine();
            System.out.println("Sender " + senderNumber + " : " + message);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (bw != null) {
                try {
                    bw.close();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

class Receiver implements Runnable {
    private static AtomicInteger receiverCount = new AtomicInteger(0);
    private String serverHost;
    private int serverPort;

    public Receiver(String serverHost, int serverPort) {
        this.serverHost = serverHost;
        this.serverPort = serverPort;
    }

    public void run() {
        BufferedReader br = null;
        BufferedWriter bw = null;
        try {
            Socket socket = new Socket(serverHost, serverPort);
            int receiverNumber = receiverCount.incrementAndGet();
            bw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream()));
            bw.write("client");
            bw.newLine();
            bw.flush();
            br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
            String message;
            while ((message = br.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println("Receiver " + receiverNumber + ": " + message);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (br != null) {
                try {
                    br.close();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            if (bw != null) {
                try {
                    bw.close();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```